# Buscar en múltiples modelos con Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, buscador

necesito de su ayuda para terminar una consulta de múltiples modelos que me tiene desconcertado hace varios días.

Tengo el siguiente controlador:

```
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::with(['category', 'ubicacion'])

            ->where('category_id', $categoria_id)
            ->when($ubicacion, function ($query) use ($ubicacion) {
                $query->whereHas('ubicacion', function ($q) use ($ubicacion) {
                    $q->ubicacion($ubicacion);
            });
        })
        ->paginate(5);
```

Funciona perfecto, pero ahora necesito traer en la búsqueda la relación con otro modelo llamado area.

Si hago la siguiente funcionalidad de forma separada, también funciona perfecto.

```
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::with(['category', 'ubicacion', 'area'])

        ->where('category_id', $categoria_id)
        ->when($area, function ($query) use ($area) {
            $query->whereHas('area', function ($q) use ($area) {
                $q->area($area);
        });
    })
    ->paginate(5);
```

Pero cuando intento unir estas consultas no me funciona. Los intentos de unión que realice:

```
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::with(['category', 'ubicacion', 'area'])
        ->where('category_id', $categoria_id)
        ->when($ubicacion && $area, function ($query) use ($ubicacion, $area) {
            
            return $query->where(function ($que) use ($ubicacion, $area) {
                
                $que->whereHas('ubicacion', function ($q) use ($ubicacion) {
                    $q->ubicacion($ubicacion);
                })->whereHas('area', function ($q) use ($area) {
                    $q->area($area);
                });
                
            });
            
        }, function ($query) use ($ubicacion, $area) {

            return $query
                ->when($ubicacion, function ($que) use ($ubicacion) {

                    $que->whereHas('ubicacion', function ($q) use ($ubicacion) {
                        $q->ubicacion($ubicacion);
                    });

                })
                ->when($area, function ($que) use ($area) {

                    $que->whereHas('area', function ($q) use ($area) {
                        $q->area($area);
                    });

                });
        })
        ->get();
```

El problema es que lo que escribe el usuario no lo busca en el like.

Me pueden brindar una mano por favor. ¡Muchas gracias!